# How to Identify Capacitor

Tags: capacitor, identification, electrolytic-capacitor

i need help to identify the following capacitors

This seems to be a 33µF at 100V but iam not sure.
[image: 1st Capacitor]

I cant identify this one. What does the small letter at the end(maybe a F) mean?
[image: 2nd Capacitor]

Comment: looks like 33uF 100V for the top one and 100uF 16V for the bottom

Comment: Why -- are you trying to replace them? They look perfectly fine to me.

Comment: @duskwuff The picture is from a monitor controler board. The monitor is flickering until it finaly stays on.The first cap is minimal inflated, but the rest of the board seems to be ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The markings on this type of capacitors usually are:

- The rated capacitance in μF (33μF for the first and 100μF for the second capacitor)
- The rated voltage in V (100V for the first and 16V for the second capacitor)
- A code indicating the group number / series code (it's the "V" on the first capacitor and the "F" on the second)
- Either date code (usually two digits) or some lot number identification, or maybe both. This is not so well defined, as far as I know.

Unfortunately I am not sure if you can find out just from these markings the manufacturer of the capacitors. But the rated capacitance and voltage information should be 33μF/100V and 100μF/16V.